# fragmentation Persian letters when using the span tag in some browsers such as chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, arabic, persian

here is a HTML code that have Persian letters in span tags and I want to style them:

```
<span class="highlight">ب</span>نیاد <span class="highlight">خ</span>یریه <span class="highlight">ح</span>مایت از <span class="highlight">ب</span>یماران <span class="highlight">س</span>رطانی
```

it works in firefox correctly but in some browsers such as chrome fragmentation Persian letters that are in span tag and not stick together.
there is a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this issue I got this answer:

```
<p><span class="highlight">ب&#x200d;</span>&#x200d;نیاد <span class="highlight">خ&#x200d;</span>&#x200d;یریه <span class="highlight">ح&#x200d;</span>&#x200d;مایت از <span class="highlight">ب&#x200d;</span>&#x200d;یماران <span class="highlight">س&#x200d;</span>&#x200d;رطانی</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From The Very Little Detail That You Said I get This

```css
.highlight{
font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="highlight">ب</span>نیاد <span class="highlight">خ</span>یریه <span class="highlight">ح</span>مایت از <span class="highlight">ب</span>یماران <span class="highlight">س</span>رطانی</p>
```

Comment: your solution did not solve my problem and Persian red letters were fragmented in code snippet.

Comment: i said you detail wasn't enough! first letter styles are usable only for alphabetically separated languages like chines or English, in your case you can style your text individually for every letter.